# "haven't a thing" or "haven't any thing (anything)"

Tags: word-choice, difference, determiners

When looking up the word "a" in a dictionary, I find this explanation.

[image: a]

If the *a* here is equal to *any*, then what's the difference in meaning (or nuance) between:

1. I simply haven't *a* thing to wear.

   and
2. I simply haven't *any* thing(anything) to wear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I haven't a thing*** is more emphatic. It can be interpreted as *I don't have even one (single) thing*.

*I simply haven't any thing(anything)* is more neutral. It only states the lack of possession.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question: Which word should be stressed in _I haven't a thing._ in this context while speaking?

Comment: There's stress on _haven't_ and then on _thing_.